# is there a method to move 'up' a Hash tree in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a 'hash tree' like this:

```
dat = {
    'building' => {'street' => 'High Street 10', 'people' =>[Person, Person]}
}
```

Person can be whatever.

So, in my code, I directly access 'building' like so: `dat['building']`, now is there a way to somehow go, up the tree, to have access to `{'building' => {...}}`, again?

I currently have a function that let's me access either of those:

```
    def info with_root = false
      with_root ? dat : dat['building']
    end #info
```

It doesn't look criminally bad (I think), but I hope there is a nicer way.

Thanks!

Comment: Not related to this question, but `'people' => [Person, Person]` is actually an array of classes, not an array of instances of people. Also, you may wish to consider using symbols rather than strings as keys.

Comment: I don't see the need to move "up". You have a handle to the top level, the variable `dat`. From that, you can reach any 'node'.

Comment: @close voters: Is the slightly broken English part of why you're voting to close?

Comment: @Andrew I know the `[Person, Person]` isn't an array of instnces; I was using pseudocode for the example above, but thanks for pointing that out, though. And I don't have control over wether they'll be strings or symbols, since I don't generate the hash. What slightly broken English part? D:

Comment: "Let's" shouldn't have an apostrophe, and you don't need a comma in "is there a way to go up the tree"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no.

The reason is this.

Suppose you have:

```
 addr = {'street' => 'High Street 10', 'people' =>[Person, Person]}
 dat1 = {'building' => addr}
 dat2 = {'zip'=>55117, 'electricBillID'=>11223344, 'address' => addr
```

What happens when you go "up"? Do you get to dat1 or dat2?

If you really need to be able to do this -- and it's not obvious that you do -- you'll need to use a more complex data structure that includes links to the containing objects -- something like a tree (https://rubygems.org/gems/rubytree) or a simple graph structure.

And, as has been mentioned, if you just hang onto the root object, you can always crawl your way back down the hash.